# Determinant of matrix transpose and Laplace expansion, application

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, collatz-conjecture, laplace-expansion

I recently read [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379504003313) in which the authors construct a matrix related to the Collatz conjecture such that

$$
m_{ij} = \begin{cases}
  1 \text{ if } i = j\\
  x \text{ if } c(i) = j\\    
  0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
where
$$
\text{where }
c(i) = \begin{cases}
  (3i+1)/2 \text{ if } i \text{ odd}\\
  i/2 \text{ if } i \text{ even}\\    
\end{cases} 
$$
is the Collatz function. They then show that for a matrix like this $M_k$ with $k$ rows and columns, if $det(M_k) = det(M_{k-1})$ then the Collatz conjecture follows.

But if $k$ is even, the only entry in the last column is a $1$ in the $(k,k)$ position. By Laplace expansion on the last column, $det(M_k)=det(M_{k-1})$ for $k$ even.

If $k$ is odd, the only entry in the last row is a $1$ in the $(k,k)$ position. So $M^T$ has only a single $1$ in the last column in the $(k,k)$ position. So by Laplace expansion on the last column, $det({M_k}^T) = det({M_{k-1}}^T)$. Since $det(M^T) = det(M)$ for any matrix $M$, $det(M_k)=det(M_{k-1})$ for $k$ odd as well.

Where is my error? Thanks.

Comment: There is no $k$ in your definition of the matrix entries, so it's not clear just what $M_k$ is.

Comment: I've edited the question to mention now that $k$ is the number of rows/columns of the matrix $M_k$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted?

Comment: Post & run is unacceptable – please return to engage with me.

Answer (score 1):

When $k=8$, $m_{5,8}=x$ because $c(5)=8$, so it's not true that the only (nonzero) entry in the last column is a one in the $(8,8)$ position. More generally, this is the case when $k\equiv8\bmod{18}$.